# Getting negative r2_score with new set of dimensions

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to predict flight `take off delay` using my current dataset. At this point of time, I only have four dimensions.

`scheduled_time_departure (A)`, `flight_id`, `day_of_week` `actual_time_departure(B)`, `take_off_delay(B-A)`

when I try to predict `actual_time_departure(B)` using scikit linear regression model using (`scheduled_time_departure (A)`, `flight_id`, `day_of_week`) on x-axis, I am getting good `r2_score`
However when I am trying to predict `take_off_delay` (which is actually difference between `actual_time_departure` and `scheduled_time_departure`), in that case I am getting negative `r2_score`.

Note:

1. to convert `string` to `integer` I am using `LabelEncoder`.
2. `scheduled_time_departure` and `actual_time_departure` are in seconds not a timestamp, that is second of day, 86400 is max value it can have.
3. I even tried doing `normalization` of `scheduled_time_departure`
4. I have ensured that `take_off_delay` is always positive.
5. For the case when I was predicting `actual_time_departure`, I tried using `one hot encoder` but that agravated `r2_score`

P.S: I am new to machine learning and data science, let me know if I am making dumb mistake :)
P.P.S: I understand model can be worst if r2 score is negative, however I want to understand the reason.

Comment: You shouldn't use flight_id in a model, as it unique for each flight and thus doesn't give information (as I understood). Also, you shouldn't use normalization, if there is such simple dependency (difference of two columns). The negative r2 score means that prediction is worse than a mean prediction. Could you try to run training without flight_id and report results?

Comment: @ViacheslavKomisarenko `flight_id` is something which is unique for given time and route. I have result both with and without normalization, however `r2_score` was negative in both case when I was predicting `take_off_delay`. However when I try to predict `actual_time_departure` I get good `r2_score`.  `take_off_delay` is absolute delta between `actual_time_departure` and `scheduled_time_departure`. Same flight_id can be repeated for multiple days.

Comment: @ViacheslavKomisarenko `flight_id` is like bus number, which can have entry for each day. I have also tried this without `flight_id` but even in those cases r2 score was negative.

Comment: It is obvious your model is not performing well. And without deep analysis it is hard to give specific guidelines. But I also agree that unique IDs are not useful unless they may appears multiple time (not just few ids being repeated!). Said that  I also note that you do not good set of features anyway, so it is not easy to fit a model. Also why linear model? Why don't you try RandomForest or Gradient Boosting Trees?

Answer (score 1):

A negative $R^2$ on your training set typically means you didn't fit an intercept. A negative $R^2$ on your test set means the model is simply very bad. Indeed flight ID is not a meaningful scalar value and can't be in a linear regression.

Comment: I'm not sure that -ve r^2 means the model has no intercept - it means in general it means the model is actually worse than just using the mean of the training data as a prediction - i.e. you've increased rather than reduced the variance of the residuals relative to y - mean(y)

Comment: That's true, but, how does one manage to do that? OP is using linear regression, and if the setup were otherwise fine and normal, that's the only way I think this can arise. Linear regression can always choose 0 coefficients and intercept = mean of the target, so shouldn't do worse. But here, I really think it's the data. The ID is (I'm guessing) huge and meaningless and dominates the regression.

Comment: Yeah that's true, plus it's not obvious from the original post but it could be the r^2 from a test set rather than the training data. They are learning ML using sklearn so most tutorials will stress doing a test/train split etc.